# Ruby 2 gem OSX sticky bit for tmpdir

Tags: ruby, rubygems, osx-mavericks

Not a Ruby developer & need help about gem install. 
I am using Osx Mavericks comes with default ruby installation 2.0. 
trying to install mctop via gem.

```
gem install mctop
```

But no luck. it fails here /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tmpdir.rb:92:in `mktmpdir': parent directory is world writable but not sticky (ArgumentError)

I have changed to tmpdir.rb file line 92 so to see which directory & it's permissions faulty. so it was a tmp folder as the ruby file name refers.   **/var/folders/zb/cwf39ww17nl0f96p678d1km40000gn/T**

my permissions for relative directories and executables are:

```
drwxr-xr-x /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/  
drwxrwxrwx /usr/bin
-r-xr-xr-x /usr/bin/ruby
-r-xr-xr-x /usr/bin/gem
drwxr-xr-x /var/folders
```

Do you know any way to fix this? google did not help :/

Comment: Using force does not work either eg: 
adding a FileUtils.chmod_R with "t" option for parent directory in tmpdir.rb file :/

Comment: Have you tried the [Getting it running](https://github.com/etsy/mctop/#getting-it-running) guide?

Comment: Wouv. i must have skipped that section. trying right now. thank you. also forgot about bundler :)

Comment: this time i got another error. even before ruby-pcap ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES) Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ruby-pcap-0.7.8/ext/Pcap.c

Comment: No idea, I've never used the Ruby version that comes with OS X …

Comment: @risyasin Did you ever resolve this? I have the same error. It disappears if I set the sticky bit to each folder in `$TMPDIR` but that's not a permanent solution.

Comment: Sadly no, i couldn't find any solution. but i have installed homebrew's ruby so i have mctop right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a quick fix. OS X uses `$TMPDIR`, so you can do:

```
chmod +t $TMPDIR
```

Comment: +1 first, Well, it's been a long time. but i think i had tried it as one of the first attempts. it was failed because gem was not using $TMPDIR or at least that package. but if it works for anyone else out there. let me know. so i choose this as an accepted answer.

Comment: I believe problem cuased by my unstable MacOS. Never got this error later.